# four in a row logic by creating AI

Tags: algorithm

I am developing 4 in a row game. in this i am creating AI.
I have used same logic as [Four in a row logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457796/four-in-a-row-logic).

in my game 0 represents empty slot. 1 represents user slot and 2 for computer slot.

now i want to develop AI such that if user means '1' are three in a row then put 2 to its 4th row.

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
>
> [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

i want to put 2 on last row 4th column after '1' like [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0] and by creating AI then what to do?

Comment: In the '4 in a row' game that I have played, cells can only be stacked one on top of the other. The cells cannot float without any support from below. Moreover your question is not clear.

Comment: In the position you have shown, your AI has already lost the game. To save the game, it will have to put 2 in both 0th and 4th column.

Comment: yes..exactly that i want to implement by creating AI.

Answer (score 2):

The AI could be implemented by using the Minimax algorithm which can be found on Wikipedia under the following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

Basically, you need a function f to decide for a state of the game whether player 1 has won (value 1) or player 2 has won (value -1) or the game has not ended yet. If the game has not ended, all moves for the current player have to be evaluated by simulating them on the board and recursively calling F again, where the respective other player is active. The value of a possible move will be the maximum of the return values of F (if player 1 is the current player) or the minimum of the return values of F (if player 2 is the current player).

At least this is the rough idea; depending on the programming language used for implementation, the evaluation logic can be implemented independently from the specific game, such that the same code can play four-in-a-row or tic-tac-toe. Furthermore, evaluation can be stopped if a move of value 1 (for player 1) or -1 (for player 2) is found, which is also termed "pruning of the search tree".

Answer (score 0):

use this part of code to prevent creating situations like 0,1,1,1,0 by user in all rows, it will return number of column that computer should play with that:

```
for(byte i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    byte min = (byte) ((i * 7) + 1);
    for(int j = 0;j<=2;j++) {
        if (boardValues[min+j] == 1 && boardValues[min + j + 1] == 1 && boardValues[min - 1 + j] == 0 && boardValues[min +j + 2] == 0) {
            if (i == 5) return (byte) ((min + j - 1)%7);
            else  if(boardValues[min - 1 + j + 7] != 0 && boardValues[min +j + 2 + 7] != 0)
                   return (byte) ((min + j - 1)%7);
        }
    }
}
```

boardValues is difined like this in my code:

```
public static byte[] boardValues = new byte[42];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe too late, but if someone is still interested to know, Here is a series of articles - http://blog.gamesolver.org/ .
It explains the concepts and logic, step by step to make a connect 4 resolver AI.