# C++ - Shortest win-checking function for tic-tac-toe?

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

This is my "getWin" function in my C++ console tic-tac-toe game. It works just fine in the scope of this simple program, but just out of curiosity, what is a shorter/more efficient way of writing a function that returns the winner (if there is one) to a tic tac toe game?

notes - winArg is either 'X' or 'O', depending on which player you're testing for. top_left, middle_center, etc. are enumerated types. the final return statement, return 'n';, is for when there isn't a winner yet.

```
char getWin(char winArg)
{
    if (board[top_left] == winArg)
    {
        if (board[top_center] == winArg)
        {
            if (board[top_right] == winArg)
                return winArg;
        }
        if (board[middle_center] == winArg)
        {
            if (board[bottom_right] == winArg)
                return winArg;
        }
        if (board[middle_left] == winArg)
        {
            if (board[bottom_left] == winArg)
                return winArg;
        }
    }
    if (board[top_right] == winArg)
    {
        if (board[middle_center] == winArg)
        {
            if (board[bottom_left] == winArg)
                return winArg;
        }
        if (board[middle_right] == winArg)
        {
            if (board[bottom_right] == winArg)
                return winArg;
        }
    }
    if (board[bottom_right] == winArg)
    {
        if (board[bottom_center] == winArg)
        {
            if (board[bottom_left] == winArg)
                return winArg;
        }
    }
    //middle vertical and horizontal lines
    if (board[top_center] == winArg && board[middle_center] == winArg && board[bottom_center] == winArg)
    {
        return winArg;
    }
    else if (board[middle_right] == winArg && board[middle_center] == winArg && board[middle_left] == winArg)
    {
        return winArg;
    }

    return 'n';
}
```

Comment: *"is there a shorter/more efficient way"* There almost always is, for any non-trivial program.

Comment: Seems like you're manually writing all the possible cases...

Comment: whoops... now it says "what is a shorter/more efficient way". lol

Comment: Yes there definitely is a prettier and more compact way (And probably a more efficient one too), I'd imagine you are relatively new to programming, am I right?
This was may be quite efficient but manually adding in cases isn't considered good practice, at all.

Comment: @Nikita that's not what Drew was trying to point out. There is almost always a better faster way to solve a problem

Comment: You could define operators like `moveUp()` and `moveRight()`, then use some loops. Is that the kind of thing you had in mind?

Comment: Perhaps try splitting up the checks, so it checks horizontals, verticals then diagonals and set the amount of "same things in a row" to three.

Comment: You could use loops yes, or you could check if a piece is touching another piece when it is placed (And is of the same type) and if the box in line with that one also has the same type then that player has won.

Comment: @KevinP. yeah... i am. it sucks, but I couldn't figure out a way to make it shorter, and this works well, so i did it anyway. im already done with the game and it works fine btw, im just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: @Nikita yeah, I get you. Tic tac toe is basically a 3x3 version of Connect-4 (in terms of win conditions)

Comment: @username_unavailable Yeah I'm new to coding. I kind of figured it would seem silly to pro programmers to just write out every case, but even after searching online I couldn't find anything prettier/quicker.

Comment: @Nikita if you tried testing for this *three-in-a-row* pattern on a 100x100 board (instead of 3x3), you would eventually *have to* discover how to use loops or some other repetitive pattern.

Comment: @DrewDormann True. Was not really thinking about connect-4 or bigger boards, but yeah it makes sense not to test for every damn case on a 100x100 board XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, in my opinion, make it more readable by factoring out the detection of a line check, something like:

```
char lineWin(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (board[a] == ' ')      return 'n';
    if (board[a] != board[b]) return 'n';
    if (board[b] != board[c]) return 'n';
    return board[a];
}
```

Then you can tidy up your full checking code with something like:

```
char getWinner(void) {
    char wnr;

    // Horizontal lines.

    if ((wnr = lineWin(top_left,    top_center,    top_right   )) != 'n') return wnr;
    if ((wnr = lineWin(middle_left, middle_center, middle_right)) != 'n') return wnr;
    if ((wnr = lineWin(bottom_left, bottom_center, bottom_right)) != 'n') return wnr;

    // Vertical lines.

    if ((wnr = lineWin(top_left,   middle_left,   bottom_left  )) != 'n') return wnr;
    if ((wnr = lineWin(top_center, middle_center, bottom_center)) != 'n') return wnr;
    if ((wnr = lineWin(top_right,  middle_right,  bottom_right )) != 'n') return wnr;

    // Diagonal lines.

    if ((wnr = lineWin(top_left,  middle_center, bottom_right  )) != 'n') return wnr;
    if ((wnr = lineWin(top_right, middle_center, bottom_left   )) != 'n') return wnr;

    return 'n';
}
```

Now keep in mind this solution is for a 3x3 Tic-Tac-Toe game. If that's all you're doing then it's ideal and much more suitable than an algorithmic solution that, for each cell, checks the eight different directions for a win while restricting checking off the edge of the board.

If you're going to design something for Connect-Four/Four-in-a-row or any other game that has a non-trivial number of ways to win, then your approach would have to be different. Although, even for that, you *still* don't have to go overboard with checking every direction from every cell, you can still use [a relatively simple algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457796/four-in-a-row-logic/15457826#15457826).

Comment: Yep that sure is more readable. I'll save formulas for bigger boards for a separate question then XD