# Check for a row of 4 diagonally, vertically, and horizontally using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom

I am making a sort of expanded tic tac toe game that is a 5x5 grid instead of a 3x3 grid and a connection of 4 needed to win instead of 3, but I have no idea how to check for a winner without checking every possible combination, and I was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction. My code is here:

```html
<style>
.tictac div {
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
height:30px;
width: 30px;
float: left;


}
.tictac{
clear: both;
}

</style>

<script>
var currentMove = 'x'
function addMove(box){

box.innerText = currentMove;
 if (currentMove === 'x'){currentMove = 'o'
}
else{currentMove = 'x'}
}

</script>
<div id = 'tictactoe'>
<div class = 'tictac'>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div  onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>
<div  onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>


</div>

<div class = 'tictac'>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>
<div  onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>


</div>

<div class = 'tictac'>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>
<div  onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>


</div>
<div>

<div class = 'tictac'>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>
<div  onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>
</div>
<div>

<div class = 'tictac'>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>
<div  onclick = 'addMove(this)'></div>
<div onclick = 'addMove(this)'> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you think you have to spell out each combination individually, which is of course not true. You need a bunch of for loops for this. The biggest issue with your code right now is that the playing field data isn't stored in a two dimensional array. This principle is called "separation of content and presentation" and is crucial to approaching problems like this from the proper direction. A user click is supposed to change your internal data structure, then you update the DOM based on it. That way you can simply iterate over your array to find the winning condition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181356/connect-four-game-checking-for-wins-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you store your game state in a 2D array (besides the management of the HTML document): that array would have 5 rows, and each row would be an array of 5 single characters. If the corresponding square has been played, it will have the name of the player ("X" or "O"). If it is empty, it could be a space " ".

There are of course several ways to check for a winning position. One way is to convert your board array to a string, where each row corresponds to 5 characters, and these rows are delimited by a special character (like #). So the total string length would be 25 + 4 = 29. Then you can make a regular expression that will find a match if there is indeed a four-in-a-row somewhere. The regular expression to detect a horizontal four in a row is simple:

```
([XO])\1{3}
```

This means: match an X or an O, and then three more of the same.

A vertical win can be matched with:

```
([XO])(.....\1){3}
```

This means: match an X or an O, and then that same character should appear exactly 6 positions further in the string (counting also the #-separator), and 12 and 18.

The "backslash" diagonal is almost the same: the distance between two consecutive hits is just one more:

```
([XO])(......\1){3}
```

The other diagonal has shorter distances, and there we need an extra precaution:

```
([XO])(?=.{0,4}#)....\1){3}
```

This means: match an X or an O, and then that same character should appear exactly 5 characters further in the string, and it should be verified that in-between those two there is a #-character, hence the `(?=` look-ahead. And this should repeat like with the other regular expressions, so to get "4 in a row".

Here is an implementation:

```js
let game = document.getElementById("tictactoe");
let board, currentPlayer;

function newGame() {
    game.innerHTML = ("<div>" + "<div></div>".repeat(5) + "</div>").repeat(5);
    board = Array.from({length: 5}, () => Array(5).fill("."));
    currentPlayer = "X";
}

function isWin() {
    let str = board.map(line => line.join("")).join("#");
    let regex = /([XO])(\1{3}|(.....\1){3}|(......\1){3}|((?=.{0,4}#)....\1){3})/;
    return regex.test(str);
}

game.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let node = e.target;
    let rowNode = node.parentNode;
    let row = Array.from(rowNode.children).indexOf(node);
    let col = Array.from(game.children).indexOf(rowNode);
    if (board[row][col] !== ".") return; // invalid move;
    node.textContent = board[row][col] = currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer = "OX"["XO".indexOf(currentPlayer)];
    if (isWin()) {
        alert("It's a win!");
        newGame();
    }
});

newGame();
```

```css
#tictactoe>div {
    clear: both;
}
#tictactoe>div>div {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="tictactoe"></div>
```