Javascript Connect Four game doesn't check for a winner diagonally
I've created the below Connect Four game using JavaScript/jQuery but the code isn't stopping when a player chooses 4 spaces diagonally. It doesn't show the congratulations message and it doesn't stop the players from playing further. There are no error messages in the console log, so I don't see why its not working as it should.


$(document).ready(function() {

  var player1Name = "";
  var player2Name = "";
  var turn = "";
  var grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ];
  var hasWinner = 0;
  var moveCount = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;

  function boardMsg(x) { // Display message function.
    return $("#message_area").text(x);
  }

  function setTurn() { // Randomly select a player to go first.
    var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
    hasWinner = 0;
    if (r == 1) {
      turn = player1Name;
      boardMsg("It's " + player1Name + "'s turn.");
    } else {
      turn = player2Name;
      boardMsg("It's " + player2Name + "'s turn.");
    }
  }

  function init() { // Initialise the grid.
    turn = "";
    grid = [
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    boardMsg("");
    $(".col").map(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("player1 player2");
    }).get();
    hasWinner = 0;
    moveCount = 0;
  }

  $("#playButton").click(function() { // Start a new game.
    if (hasWinner == 1) {
      init();
    }
    player1Name = $("#player-1-inp").val();
    player2Name = $("#player-2-inp").val();
    if (player1Name == "" || player2Name == "") {
      $("<div>Please enter player names.</div>").dialog({
        title: "ALERT!"
      });
      return;
    }
    setTurn();
  });

  $(".col").click(function() { // Process mouse clicks for both players.
    player1Name = $("#player-1-inp").val();
    player2Name = $("#player-2-inp").val();
    if (player1Name == "" || player2Name == "") {
      $("<div>Please enter player names.</div>").dialog({
        title: "ALERT!"
      });
      return;
    }
    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    var col = $(this).index();
    if (grid[row][col] !== 0) {
      $("<div>This position has already been filled.</div>").dialog({
        title: "ALERT!"
      });
      return;
    }
    if (hasWinner == 1) {
      $("<div>To start another game, click Play again.</div>").dialog({
        title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
      });
      return;
    }
    if (turn == player1Name) {
      moveCount++;
      $(this).addClass("player1");
      grid[row][col] = 1;
      var ifWon = winnerCheck(1, player1Name);
      if (!ifWon) {
        if (moveCount >= 49) {
          boardMsg("Match Drawn!");
          moveCount = 0;
          hasWinner = 1;
          $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
            title: "MATCH DRAWN!"
          });
          return;
        } else {
          turn = player2Name;
          boardMsg("It's " + player2Name + "'s turn.");
        }
        return;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    } else if (turn == player2Name) {
      moveCount++;
      $(this).addClass("player2");
      grid[row][col] = 2;
      var ifWon = winnerCheck(2, player2Name);
      if (!ifWon) {
        if (moveCount >= 49) {
          boardMsg("Match Drawn!");
          moveCount = 0;
          hasWinner = 1;
          $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
            title: "MATCH DRAWN!"
          });
          return;
        } else {
          turn = player1Name;
          boardMsg("It's " + player1Name + "'s turn.");
        }
        return;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  });

  function winnerCheck(n, playerName) { // Check for winner.
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { // check for winner by row.
      if (
        (grid[i][0] == n && grid[i][1] == n && grid[i][2] == n && grid[i][3] == n) ||
        (grid[i][1] == n && grid[i][2] == n && grid[i][3] == n && grid[i][4] == n) ||
        (grid[i][2] == n && grid[i][3] == n && grid[i][4] == n && grid[i][5] == n) ||
        (grid[i][3] == n && grid[i][4] == n && grid[i][5] == n && grid[i][6] == n)) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { // check for winner by column.
      if (
        (grid[0][i] == n && grid[1][i] == n && grid[2][i] == n && grid[3][i] == n) ||
        (grid[1][i] == n && grid[2][i] == n && grid[3][i] == n && grid[4][i] == n) ||
        (grid[2][i] == n && grid[3][i] == n && grid[4][i] == n && grid[5][i] == n) ||
        (grid[3][i] == n && grid[4][i] == n && grid[5][i] == n && grid[6][i] == n)) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    // diagonal winner forwards
    if (x < 4 && y < 4) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x + 1][y + 1] == n && grid[x + 2][y + 2] == n && grid[x + 3][y + 3] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (x < 5 && x > 0 && y < 5 && y > 0) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x + 1][y + 1] == n && grid[x + 2][y + 2] == n && grid[x - 1][y - 1] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (x < 6 && x > 1 && y < 6 && y > 1) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x + 1][y + 1] == n && grid[x - 1][y - 1] == n && grid[x - 2][y - 2] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (x > 2 && y > 2) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x - 1][y - 1] == n && grid[x - 2][y - 2] == n && grid[x - 3][y - 3] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    // diagonal winner backwards
    if (x < 4 && y > 2) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x + 1][y - 1] == n && grid[x + 2][y - 2] == n && grid[x + 3][y - 3] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (x > 0 && x < 6 && y < 5 && y > 0) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x + 1][y - 1] == n && grid[x + 2][y - 2] == n && grid[x - 1][y + 1] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (x > 1 && x < 5 && y < 4 && y > 1) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x + 1][y - 1] == n && grid[x - 2][y + 2] == n && grid[x - 1][y + 1] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (x > 2 && y < 4) {
      if (grid[x][y] == n && grid[x - 3][y + 3] == n && grid[x - 2][y + 2] == n && grid[x - 1][y + 1] == n) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
          title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
<h1> Connect Four </h1>
<div id="game_board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="0"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="1"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="2"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="3"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="4"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="5"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="6"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="7"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="8"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="9"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="10"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="11"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="12"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="13"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="14"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="15"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="16"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="17"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="18"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="19"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="20"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="21"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="22"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="23"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="24"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="25"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="26"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="27"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="28"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="29"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="30"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="31"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="32"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="33"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="34"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="35"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="36"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="37"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="38"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="39"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="40"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="41"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" id="42"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="43"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="44"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="45"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="46"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="47"> </div>
    <div class="col" id="48"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="panel">
  <input type="text" id="player-1-inp" placeholder="Player 1 Name">
  <input type="text" id="player-2-inp" placeholder="Player 2 Name">
  <button id="playButton">PLAY</button>
  <div id="message_area">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



Would someone be able to help me and let me know what's wrong with my code please?

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

What should we do with "It's b's turn." in the above's demo to reproduce the issue?

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63446171/383904 or https://medium.com/@jsymondst/how-would-you-find-a-win-in-a-connect-four-grid-c514f6fc7fb7

Please provide a an example that actually shows the error. You current code just switches the output between "It's foo's turn" and "It's bar's turn" ...

There is no error, it just lets the players keep playing unless they get 4 in a row horizontally or vertically

But your code doesn't allow to play, because it doesn't show a board. A click on PLAY (the only thing you can do) just writes "It's x's turn .."

@EmmaRakauskas: "There is no error" - Perhaps not an error message or runtime exception (unless you're not familiar with where to see those), but presumably there is at least a problem to be demonstrated.  Can you clarify how specifically to test the code snippet in the question to demonstrate that problem?  And within the considerable amount of code provided, can you clarify which operation isn't producing the result you expect?

It must be wrong logic checking for diagonals win in function winnerCheck
But first let's "optimize"
Instead of:
// checking rows
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (
        (grid[i][0] == n && grid[i][1] == n && grid[i][2] == n && grid[i][3] == n) ||
        (grid[i][1] == n && grid[i][2] == n && grid[i][3] == n && grid[i][4] == n) ||
        (grid[i][2] == n && grid[i][3] == n && grid[i][4] == n && grid[i][5] == n) ||
        (grid[i][3] == n && grid[i][4] == n && grid[i][5] == n && grid[i][6] == n)) {
        boardMsg("Congratulations " + playerName + " you have won!");
        hasWinner = 1;
        moveCount = 0;
        $("<div>To start a new game, click the Play button.</div>").dialog({
            title: "CONGRATULATIONS!"
        });
        return true;
    }
}

You can use loops instead of repetitions:
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 3 ; j++) {
        let win = true;
        for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (grid[i][j + k] != n) {
                win = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (win) {
            // congratulations
            return true 
        }
    }
}

Similiar for columns:
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 3 ; j++) {
        let win = true;
        for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (grid[j + k][i] != n) {
                win = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (win) {
            // congratulations
            return true 
        }
    }
}

We can sort of combine to have diagonal check:
for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        let win = true;
        for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (grid[i + k][j + k] != n) {
                win = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (win) {
            // congratulations
            return true
        }
    }
}

And the last diagonal is also similiar. Answer in the comments below.

Thank you, I'll give that a go
